# Spring Boot Repository Native Query for DTO in Postgresql Issue

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, nativequery

I have a problem about writing a native query for dto in Spring Boot with the usage of Postgresql.

Here is the dto shown below.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserCommentsResponse {
    private String placeName;
    private String text;
}
```

Here is the native query shown below.

```
@Query(value="SELECT new com.demo.project.dao.UserCommentsResponse(placeName, text) FROM comment c inner join place p on p.id = c.place_id where customer_id = :id", nativeQuery=true)
List<UserCommentsResponse> getUsersComments(int id);
```

Here is the error message shown below.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Query(value="SELECT UserCommentsResponse(placeName, text) FROM comment c inner join place p on p.id = c.place_id where customer_id = :id", nativeQuery=true)
```

instead of your original query

Comment: it didn't help me fix the issue.